# EasyMock doesn't use mocked method

Tags: spring, easymock

I created the following test.

```
@Test
public void whenCreate_ThenAccountsShouldBeFound() {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setUsername("Test");
    account.setFirstName("FirstName");
    account.setLastName("LastName");
    account.setPassword("Password");
    account.setEmail("maxmuster@hs-pforzheim.de");
    accountService.createAccount(account);

    Account a = new Account();
    a.setUsername("Teswt");
    a.setFirstName("FirstName");
    a.setLastName("LastName");
    a.setPassword("Password");
    a.setEmail("maxmustee@hs-pforzheim.de");
    accountService.createAccount(a);
    AccountRepository accountRepository = createNiceMock(AccountRepository.class);
    expect(accountRepository.findAll()).andReturn(Collections.singletonList(a));
    replay(accountRepository);

    assertEquals("Username name should be Test", "Test", accountService.getAllAccounts().iterator().next().getUsername());
}
```

The test passed but I dont know why. Normally the mocked method should return another object, which should result in a wrong test result. For me it seems, that the mocked method is not working, but why?

Comment: You need to give the tested code in order to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Mock is correct. Just your code is wrong.

You created a mock for AccountRepository but you didn't set this mock into accountService. So when you call accountService.getAllAccounts(), that accountService will call to real AccountRepository, not the mocked one. Therefore, you will get 2 written elements in DB.

And, assert is correct when compare "Test" with the first element of return list.

To fix, just need to set the AccountRepository to accountService

```
AccountRepository accountRepository = createNiceMock(AccountRepository.class);
accountService.setAccountRespository(accountRepository);
```

That's all
Thanks, Linh